Is it possible to return statically stored values as references from a function?
I am fairly new to Rust. I would like to be able to create a variable with static lifetime from within a function and return a reference to it.
How would one accomplish the following in Rust:
std::vector<int>& get_ints() {
   static bool run_yet = false;
   static std::vector<int> ints;
   if ( ! run_yet ) {
       run_yet = true;
       for ( int i=0; i < 10; ++i ) {
           ints.push_back(i);
       }
   }
   return ints;
}

I believe this may have something to do with lifetimes, but I'm not sure.

Are you asking about static OnceCell object?

To be clear, ints is not heap-allocated in your example code. It owns a heap allocation, but you're not returning a reference to the heap allocation here. You're returning a reference to the value that owns the allocation. The fact that a heap allocation even happens is really an implementation detail, so your question is not really related to heap allocations in any meaningful sense. (You could ask the same thing about an array, for example, which wouldn't be heap allocated.)

OnceLock does what you are looking for. It will run the code in get_or_init only if it has not been run before.
use std::sync::OnceLock;

pub fn get_ints() -> &'static [u32] {
    static CELL: OnceLock<Vec<u32>> = OnceLock::new();
    CELL.get_or_init(|| (0..10).collect()).as_slice()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", get_ints());
}

playground

It's pretty pointless to return a Vec though if it isn't mut ... &'static [u32] would be more 'best practice'.

absolutely right, edited accordingly.

Personally I'd go further and store it on the heap in a Box<[u32]>.  Also small nits: ::<Vec<u32>> is superfluous as it can be inferred, and .as_slice() is superfluous as it'd be auto-deref coerced.  playground

Oh, also, the OP excluded 10 so the correct range would be 0..10.
